# How to stop timezone conversion completely in jackson or Jackson should not apply local offset in any case

Tags: json, rest, date, spring-mvc, jackson

In Spring-REST API project, I have a scenario where I am using Jackson annotation on date type field of the class.

There are such scenarios where front-end is sending data in JSON format and this will be auto-mapped with POJO at API(server) side by Jackson internally.

So Jackson library automatically converts that date-time value from JSON data with server's timezone.

I know there is one option to stop timezone conversion if timezone info is present in JSON data (using below)

> this.disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE);

But I need a configuration/setting, Using which Jackson should not apply timezone conversion for incoming JSON date data for any use case.

Please provide snippet if anyone have. It will be more helpful.